# JPA+Hibernate - dynamic OneToMany relation in Entity

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a Entity class which has a self referential relation b/w ID (primary key) and PARENT_ID.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DIRECTORY")
    public class DirectoryEntity{


        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Integer id;


        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = true)
        private Set<DirectoryEntity> children;
}
```

Everything is working fine when I fetched records it mapped the child records to children array. But I have a situation where I have a following query.

```
        SELECT 
                 dqlist.*, 
                 score(1) AS rank 
             FROM 
                 DIRECTORY dqlist 
             WHERE 
                 contains(dqlist.ESTABLISHMENT_NAME_EN,'definescore(fuzzy("SEARCH_TEXT", 1, 6, weight),relevance)',1) > 0 ) 
       ORDER BY 
         rank DESC
```

This query fetch all the records which fulfill the search condition. In my case I only want those child records which fulfill the search condition but here I am also getting those child records which doesn't follow the condition they are getting displayed because they have a reference of a parent record which does follow this search condition. Is there any way in which I only show those child records which obey the search condition?

Comment: Adding `PARENT_ID is not null` will result in only getting records that are children of some parent. I think that should resolve your case?

Answer (score 0):

So here is my solution.

I didn't find a JPA way to cater my problem and self join also have some performance issue for my case. So what I did is wrote a query which returns all the records which fulfill the search conditions with their parent records and map the parent-child relation in the code.

Here is my code which map child objects to their parent object:

```
    public List<DirectoryEntity> convertListToTree(List<DirectoryEntity> records){
    Map<Integer,DirectoryEntity> treeMap = new HashMap<>();
    treeMap = records.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(DirectoryEntity::getId, x -> x));
    if(!treeMap.isEmpty() && !records.isEmpty()) {
        for (Iterator<DirectoryEntity> iterator = records.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            DirectoryEntity record = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("ID: " +record.getId()+ " PARENT_ID: " + record.getParentId());
            Integer parentId = record.getParentId();
            if(parentId!=null) {
                DirectoryEntity parentRecord = treeMap.get(parentId);
                if(parentRecord!=null) {
                    if(parentRecord.getChilds()==null) {                            
                        parentRecord.setChilds(new HashSet<>());
                        parentRecord.getChilds().add(record);                           
                    }else {
                        parentRecord.getChilds().add(record);                           
                    }                       

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return treeMap.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(x->x.getParentId()==null)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

If someone has any better solution please feel free to answer I would really appreciate. :)